# parse json file ValueError

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

Hi I have a json file and want to parse it. I wrote the follwoing code:

```
import json as simplejson
import os

for filename in os.listdir('/home/Documents/test/'):
    with open('/home/Documents/test/' + filename) as file:
            data = simplejson.load(file)
            try:
                if(data['scans']['Microsoft']['detected']==True):
                    label = data['scans']['Microsoft']['result']
                    print label
            except (ValueError, KeyError, TypeError):
                print "JSON format error"
```

But I got the following error:

```
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)
```

Could you help me what is the problem. I think because my file include unicode characters but I do not know how can I solve it.

This is the part of my json file:

```
{u'md5': u'0a1cdc568b4da42cb7acce45834eb4ba',
 u'permalink': u'https://www.virustotal.com/file/a0acc0feb1da7f571faaa7dc3b7ebcd1b856710d1f44cd6e0b57ec5a9bc70038/analysis/1383102973/',
 u'positives': 42,
 u'resource': u'0A1CDC568B4DA42CB7ACCE45834EB4BA',
 u'response_code': 1,
 u'scan_date': u'2013-10-30 03:16:13',
 u'scan_id': u'a0acc0feb1da7f571faaa7dc3b7ebcd1b856710d1f44cd6e0b57ec5a9bc70038-1383102973',
 u'scans': {u'AVG': {u'detected': True,
                     u'result': u'FakeAV.AFQQ',
                     u'update': u'20131029',
                     u'version': u'13.0.0.3169'},
            u'Agnitum': {u'detected': True,
                         u'result': u'FraudTool.Agent!dfdcHBsNM3c',
                         u'update': u'20131029',
                         u'version': u'5.5.1.3'},
            u'AhnLab-V3': {u'detected': True,
                           u'result': u'Trojan/Win32.FakeAV',
                           u'update': u'20131029',
                           u'version': u'2013.10.30.01'},
            u'AntiVir': {u'detected': True,
                         u'result': u'TR/Winwebsec.bamnx',
                         u'update': u'20131030',
                         u'version': u'7.11.110.26'},
            u'Antiy-AVL': {u'detected': False,
                           u'result': None,
                           u'update': u'20131029',
                           u'version': u'2.0.3.7'},
```

Comment: You don't have JSON. You have Python literals.

Comment: What do you mean by that? my file has the json extention..

Comment: Either fix the program that created the file (don't use `pprint.pformat()`, use `json.dumps()`) or use `ast.literal_eval()` to produce Python objects from that string.

Comment: @Alex: Just because it has a .json extension doesn't mean it is actual JSON data. It is not. It contains Python 2 literal syntax.

Comment: @Martijn: Thanx for your info. I thought it is a standard json file since I got them from virus total website..

Comment: Are you sure you haven't de- and encoded that JSON again? I really doubt a major site would serve such non-JSON JSON.

Comment: @Alex: looking at the [API documentation](https://www.virustotal.com/en/documentation/public-api/) it looks like they return valid JSON. How did you get that file?

Comment: @MartijnPieters i got it from here https://github.com/Xen0ph0n/VirusTotal_API_Tool/ and use vtlite.py to generate json file

Comment: @Alex: note the use of `pprint()` in that script. The script loads the data as JSON, decodes it to Python then prints the Python structure. Line 67 uses `pprint(it, jsondumpfile)`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have JSON data. You have Python literals (Python syntax defining dictionaries, booleans, strings and `None` objects just like you'd find these in Python source code).

JSON data doesn't use single quotes for strings nor are they prefixed with `u`, but Python 2 `unicode` objects *are*. JSON uses `null` where Python uses `None`, `false` and `true` where Python uses `False` and `True`.

Either fix the process that creates the file (it looks like the output the `pprint` module would produce) to actually produce JSON, or use the [`ast.literal_eval()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to safely convert the string back to Python objects.

If you are using [the scripts from this repository](https://github.com/Xen0ph0n/VirusTotal_API_Tool), know that the `--jsondump` switch does **not** produce JSON output. The scripts load JSON from the API into a Python structure, and the switch merely dumps that structure to the file *as Python literals*:

```
if jsondump == True:
  jsondumpfile = open("VTDL" + md5 + ".json", "w")
  pprint(it, jsondumpfile)
  jsondumpfile.close()
  print "\n\tJSON Written to File -- " + "VTDL" + md5 + ".json"
```

Note the `pprint()` call there. If you need to load JSON into your own Python code, write your own API calls rather than rely on this script.